# Wordpress абсолютные ссылки

Tags: wordpress, ссылки

Подскажите пожалуйста, а можно ли как то предотвратить запись в базу данных абсолютных путей на посты, вложения и тд?
Я пытался искать, но все решения связаны с *исправлением* уже добавленных абсолютных ссылок. А нужно, после того, как исправил - больше так не делать)

Comment: И каковы причины такого желания? "шоб було" или всё же есть веские доводы за относительные ссылки?

Comment: @SeVlad ну как вариант сайт переехал на https, но предполагается, что в будущем может вернуться обратно на http (видела такое)

Comment: @SeVlad опять мы тут с тобой вдвоём общаемся. Очередной вопрос в стиле "выстрелил и забыл"))

Comment: Не, не "выстрелил и забыл". вот снова рабочий день, и я читаю)
Доводы следующие. Сейчас я разрабатываю сайт локально, а на промежуточный тестовый сервак перенес с помощью Duplicator, как указано ниже) Но, допустим, ситуация. Хочется потестить контент на локальной машине, а потом в случае успеха - выгрузить на промежуточный сервер для тестов там. И, если бы ссылки были относительными, я бы просто залил обновленную БД на сервер, и все. Но вообще, и правда, надо изучить доводы в пользу абсолютных урлов

Comment: @KAGGDesign да, твои предположения оказались верными. Я подумал про другое :) Но тогда Александр, однозначно дубликатор или аналоги (есть отдельный скрипт, но с ним тяжелее для неопытных). Всё потому, что не только в урла дело. Даже если бы они были относительными - при переносе всё равно может всё поломаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно. Весь функционал ядра WordPress построен на том предположении, что пишутся абсолютные ссылки. Вам придётся перекроить всё ядро.

В то же время, за использованием абсолютных ссылок в WordPress лежат серьезные доводы. Почитайте [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516783/6817117) на английском StackOverflow, в котором даны объяснения. В том числе, приведено мнение одного из ведущих разработчиков WordPress.

Так что лучше не ломать то, что построено, а приспособиться к этому. Единственная проблема, которая возникает при использовании абсолютных ссылок - перенос сайтов. Пользуйтесь плагином [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) и вы избежите возможных проблем.

А перенос сайта с относительными ссылками в общем случае ещё более проблематичен. В упомянутом ответе это тоже обсуждается.

Comment: Дубликатор и КО нужны не столько для замены ссылок, сколько для исправления сериальных данных. А проблема при текущем положении всё же есть.. Точнее может быть.. (как правило от дурной головы), но я об этом потом расскажу, когда ТС ответит на мой вопрос :)

Comment: Да и для замены "простых" ссылок Duplicator нужен. Как их менять? Руками? В текстовом редакторе по дампу базы?

Comment: Для чего менять? В каком случае?

Comment: @SeVlad при переносе, само собой

Comment: При переносе (на др хостинг я полагаю имеется ввиду?) без замены адреса что менять? ПУТИ к файлам!!! А они мало того, что будут изменены  - они в сериалах как правило. Вот для этого дубликатор и нужен. Но в вопросе ТСа про адреса на сайте Т.е. то что на фронте. Без всяких переносов и тп. С дубликатором ты конечно прав, но это может его запутать тк задача (как обычно :) ) не ясна.

Comment: @SeVlad ну конечно, я о переносе на другой домен. Я вопрос видел, а ответ расширил (предполагая причину нелюбви к относительным ссылкам)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68083/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-sevlad).

Comment: @SeVlad Я ответил на ваш вопрос выше. Вообще, в силу не богатого опыта, еще не знаю всех возможных проблем, с которыми можно столкнуться при попытках избавиться от абсолютных урлов.  А вопрос о переносе сайта, как верно догадались, конечно же стоит)

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Полезно все, что было отвечено мне, спасибо)

Comment: @Александр на наши междусобойчики внимания можно не обращать, мы давно тут тусуемся))

Comment: @KAGGDesign в чате обещанное.